# WCF Data Service : How to query ALL entities when Paging is enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have enabled paging at my service level : config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 25);

Now, whenever I try to query all my entities at client level, I only get 25 entities.

How do I get everything ? what code should I write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryOperationResponse.GetContinuation() is what you are looking for.  Sample code for using this in a loop at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358711.aspx

Comment: How do you detect from the client wether Paging is turned on at the client level or not ?

Comment: If the query you issued returned no next link (that is they GetContinuation returns null) then you got all the results. That should be all you need to know on the client. Just handle all responses as if they do use paging, those which won't will never return you the continuation, so your client will work.